# Javascript function called by call and apply can't handle a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, call, undefined

Can somebody please explain why the below code returns undefined 2 times ?

```
    var test = function (theArr) {
        alert(theArr);
    };

    test.call(6);               //Undefined

    var theArgs = new Array();
    theArgs[0] = 6;

    test.apply(theArgs)         //Undefined
```

Comment: Why do you need to use the call method?

Comment: You mean that it shows "Undefined" in the alert dialog, right? Because there are not return values anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for the JavaScript call method:

`fun.call(object, arg1, arg2, ...)`

The syntax for the JavaScript apply method:

`fun.apply(object, [argsArray])`

The main difference is that call() accepts an argument list, while apply() accepts a single array of arguments.

So if you want to call a function which prints something and pass an object scope for it to execute in, you can do:

```
function printSomething() {
    console.log(this);
}

printSomething.apply(new SomeObject(),[]); // empty arguments array
// OR
printSomething.call(new SomeObject()); // no arguments
```

Comment: So to explicitly solve the given code: `test.call(this, 6);` or `test.apply(this, theArgs);`

Comment: Thanks! I am switching back from Jquery to the basics of Javascript at the moment and it takes some getting used too :)

Comment: To further clarify: the `Object` parameter specifies what the `this` keyword will refer to when the function is executed.